# How do I get the email address of the person who clicked the link in the email?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I am working with Google App Engine python version. The app sends an 
email to the user with a link to a page to upload an image as an 
avatar. It would be nice to have the email so that I can associate the 
avatar with that email. How can I get the email of the person who just clicked the link? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put a hash in the URL that uniquely identifies the address you sent it to.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain a bit more about how this is done. So, say, the app sends this link in the email `http://helloworld.appspot.com/upload#az@example.com` And the `az@example.com` clicks on this link. How do I pick up the email to form this query: `q = User.all()
 q.filter("userEmail =", emailAddress)`? Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Well, you can't, since the fragment is not sent to the server. Use something like `http://helloworld.appspot.com/welcome/ag4d65th4g8` instead, where the `ag4d65th4g8` is stored in a database next to `az@example.com`. Scrape the path info in order to get the hash.

Comment: thanks but I don't understand how to do this. I will have to use a form asking for the email. I was trying to avoid that but what you are suggesting makes no sense to me. I have no idea how you `scrape` the path or how you store the key `next to` the email. Thanks anyway.

Comment: He didn't mean a literal 'hash' character - he meant a cryptographic hash. A simpler idea is to generate a UUID or other unique number and use that to look up a database record with the user's email - just don't use sequential IDs, or users will be able to find other users' records.

Comment: but if the person (that have the UUID asigned) forward the email.. and someone else was the interested on the link. how to track that?

Comment: This isn't a good solution since the person could forward the email to someone else, which would make a hardcoded hash misidentify the respondent.